# Is it possible to know the origin of SoapClient request?

Tags: php, soap-client

I need to use the [SoapClient PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) function to use a service from another site that will give me a certain information.

Can they know from what site came that request?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you put this code (example)

```
function get_base_domain_by_name ( $name ) {
if (is_string($name) && preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+$/i', $name) === 1) {
    $parts = array_reverse(explode('.', strtolower($name)));
    $base  = array_shift($parts);
    foreach ($parts as $part ) {
        $base = $part.'.'.$base;
        if (( $addr = gethostbyname($base) ) != $base && preg_match('/^[0-9\.]+$/', $addr) === 1 ) {
            return($base);
        }
    }
}
return(false);

}

function get_base_domain_by_addr ( $addr ) {
    return(get_base_domain_by_name(gethostbyaddr($addr)));
}
$domain =  get_base_domain_by_addr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $domain;
```

You can get the URL of the of the Site that accessed you, and if you use: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] you can get the IP Address.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do i put this in the file that is accessed? Thank you.